# how to add valiation in SAP Ui5, in input field that user side mandatory to enter only numbers with corresponding maximum length and minimum length,

Tags: sapui5

how to add valiation in SAP Ui5,

1st case-  in input field that user side mandatory to enter only numbers with corresponding maximum length and minimum length, 
2nd case - in input field that user side mandatory to enter only alpabet with corresponding maximum length and minimum length,.
In both case user also can`t use special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using a [sap.m.MaskInput](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MaskInput): this control allows users to enter data in a certain format and in a fixed-width input.

EDIT: 
`MaskInput` forces users to use the correct set of input data. You can then perform the validation in the `change` event of the input.

For Example (straight from [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MaskInput/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput))

```
            <Label text="8 Latin characters (case sensitive)"
                   tooltip="8 Latin characters (case sensitive)"/>
            <MaskInput mask="CCCCCCCC" placeholderSymbol="_" placeholder="Enter text">
                <rules>
                    <MaskInputRule maskFormatSymbol="C" regex="[A-Z]"/>
                </rules>
            </MaskInput>

            <Label text="Numeric only" tooltip="Numeric only"/>
            <MaskInput mask="999999" placeholderSymbol="_" placeholder="Enter a six digit number"/>
```

Comment: can you please give me example of code as per my requirement..?

Comment: Thanks for your help, another thing Can we also use validation like by giving error hints as a tooltip like, we can use only 1. ALPHANUMERIC format data, 2. can1t use special character 3. Can also use maximum/minimum length limit

Comment: Check this two links, I think the answers to your questions are here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked and https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputValueState. You can use types for validation and leverage the properties valueState and valueStateText. The links refer to sap.m.Input but apply also to sap.m.MaskInput (and other controls in general)

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to set constraints for inputs, like this:

```
<Input value="{ path: 'BusinessAddress/PostalCode', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.String' , constraints:{search: '^[0-9]*$'}}">
```

Comment: I tried with this         <Input id="IDEGen_input5" placeholder="Enter number" value="{ path: 'BusinessAddress/PostalCode', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.String' , constraints:{search: '^[0-9]*$'}}">  but still the same, not working validation